# executing python in codeigniter with exec command

Tags: python, php, codeigniter, exec

When executing with php the exec command in codeIgniter

```
$data=exec("/usr/bin/python python.py");

$data=exec("/usr/bin/python3.6 python36.py");
```

the first one with python (which point on python 2.7.5) works fine
but when calling the second line with python3.6 it doesn't work.

I precise that at the root of my project, both are working !
That's why I can't understand why in CodeIgniter the first is ok but not the second one.
(security options in codeIgniter ?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have tested something else and the result is that it is not a python3.6 problem but the access to selenium (import selenium) that can't be executed in codeIgniter but works well when executed in my root project. Any idea ? Thanks